# How do I access gitlab api using python-gitlab?

Tags: python, gitlab

According to the python-gitlab documentation, I need a gitlab.cfg file that should look something like this:

```
[global]
default = gitlabcom
ssl_verify = true
timeout = 30


[gitlabcom]
url = https://gitlab.com/
private_token = PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
api_version = 4
```

and then I should be able to list my projects with

```
gitlab -c gitlab.cfg project list
```

however, this gives me a list of projects that are not mine, e.g. (the list varies):

```
id: 13784565
path: 2019-08-25-form-from-classes

id: 13784562
path: faq

id: 13784561
path: curso-web-playground

id: 13784560
...
```

If I use curl I get the expected results:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/42424242/projects"
```

(where `42424242` is my group id).

I can't find any documentation on how to do this with gitlab.com (as opposed to a privately hosted gitlab instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `project list` command takes `-h` (help) flag:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\gitlabtst> gitlab -c gitlab.cfg project list -h
usage: gitlab project list [-h] [--sudo SUDO] [--search SEARCH]
                           [--owned OWNED] [--starred STARRED]
                           [--archived ARCHIVED] [--visibility VISIBILITY]
                           [--order-by ORDER_BY] [--sort SORT]
                           [--simple SIMPLE] [--membership MEMBERSHIP]
                           [--statistics STATISTICS]
                           [--with-issues-enabled WITH_ISSUES_ENABLED]
                           [--with-merge-requests-enabled WITH_MERGE_REQUESTS_ENABLED]
                           [--with-custom-attributes WITH_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES]
                           [--page PAGE] [--per-page PER_PAGE] [--all]
```

To list all *my* projects is therefore:

```
gitlab -c gitlab.cfg project list --owned=1 --all
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a hacky way to do it (hopefully someone will come up with a better answer):

```
gitlab -c gitlab.cfg -o json -f projects group get --id 42424242  | jq .projects[].name
```

where

```
gitlab -c gitlab.cfg -o json -f projects group get --id 42424242
```

gets all the data for the single group with id 42424242, as json (`-o json`) and prints only the projects field (`-f projects` - this can be skipped).  The returned value looks like

```
{
    "projects": [
        {...lots of fields..., "name": "<project-name>", ...even more fields...}
        ...
    ]
}
```

then I pipe through jq (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
 | jq .projects[].name
```

which says, go into projects (`.projects`), iterate over all items in the list (`.projects[]`), and then extract the name from each list item (`.projects[].name`).

The result is:

```
"project1"
"project2"
"project3"
...
```